# Saving to Lists in Sub BUs in Enterprise 2.0 account

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, enterprise, ssjs

I'm working on a landing page that is serving as a profile/preference center and is hosted in the top level BU in an Enterprise 2.0 account. The page displays several attributes (first name, last name etc) and about 10 check boxes that are Lists in 10 different BUs. Using AmpScript, I can get the status of each of the lists by using a complex filter and setting the "QueryAllAccounts" Property to true. When saving the subscriber, I thought I could make a single InvokeCreate/InvokeUpdate on the Subscriber by setting the Client property to the appropriate BU MID for each of the 10 SubscriberLists I attach to the Subscriber.  However, I get an error stating "list not found".

As a work around, I'm making 10 InovkeCreate/InvokeUpdate on the Subscriber by setting Subscriber Client property to the appropriate BU MID for each of the ten SubscriberLists. This works but is a bit slow and will only get slower with additional Lists/BUs. Which leads to my question - should I be able to save a Subscriber that has multiple SubscriberLists from different BU's in one Invoke call?

Comment: Greg: could you post your code please, both desired and workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you can do it in a single call. Just set the ClientID on the Subscriber object, not the SubscriberList object.